# ASP.NET MVC3 ForEach on Two Different Data Structures

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I understand how to handle a foreach loop over a single data structure using page inheritance in ASP.NET MVC, but I want to display the contents of two different types of data on the same page. How can this be done since pages only accept one class for inheritance?

Comment: You mean two different models?

Comment: Strongly typed partial views, or build a separate composite model that combines the two, and bind to it.

Comment: Do you mean passing a model to a view?  If not, what do you mean by "using page inheritance"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the guys before me pointed out, the correct answer if we understood you correctly is [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). The idea is to give the page one model, which contains two other models, eg.

```
public class Car {
    public Motor Engine { get; set; }
    public List<Seat> Seats { get; set; }
}
```

The idea here is that your class now derives from `ViewPage<Car>`, which allows you to do this:

Sitting behing a <%= Model.Engine.ToString() %> engine, there are:

```
<ul>
<% foreach(var seat in Model.Seats) { %>
       <li><%= seat.ToString() %>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: What a simple approach. Thanks for that mind-numbingly easy concept :)

Answer (score 3):

I know of these two choices:

1. Make a class that contains both subclasses (a view model).
2. Use ViewData or ViewBag to pass one or more of the instances to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Composition

```
public class CompositeViewModel
{
    public ViewModelClass1 ViewModel1 { get; set; }
    public ViewModelClass2 ViewModel2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model class.

```
class ViewModel 
{
    MyClass1 Object1 { get; set; }
    MyClass2 Object2 { get; set; }
}
```